# How do I read-write multiple lines in client-server app in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, client-server

I have a multi-thread Java client-server app and found myself struggling with multiple lines communication. Here's what I mean

If I write a Server like this:

```
private static void startHandler(final Socket socket)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Scanner inputFromUser = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    PrintStream outPutToUser = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    outPutToUser.println("Welcome!");
                    System.out.println(inputFromUser.nextLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }
```

And write Client like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner inputFromUser = new Scanner(System.in);
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
        Scanner inputFromServer = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintStream outputToServer = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        String greetingFromServer = inputFromServer.nextLine();
        System.out.println(greetingFromServer);
        outputToServer.println(inputFromUser.nextLine());
    }
```

It works so well:

- Server sends "Welcome" to the client
- User input some string
- This string gets printed in the server console

But if I try to make it more complicated like this:

```
private static void startHandler(final Socket socket)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try {
                    Scanner inputFromUser = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                    PrintStream outPutToUser = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    outPutToUser.println("Welcome!");
                    sendInitialCommandsToUser(outPutToUser);
                    System.out.println(inputFromUser.nextLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }

    private static void sendInitialCommandsToUser(PrintStream writer)
    {
        writer.println("1 - Log In");
        writer.println("2 - Sign up");
        writer.println("3 - Exit");
    }
```

Client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner inputFromUser = new Scanner(System.in);

        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
        Scanner inputFromServer = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintStream outputToServer = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        String greetingFromServer = inputFromServer.nextLine();
        System.out.println(greetingFromServer);

        getMultipleLinesFromServer(inputFromServer);

        outputToServer.println(inputFromUser.nextLine());
    }

    private static void getMultipleLinesFromServer(Scanner scanner)
    {
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
    }
```

It get's stucked on  `getMultipleLinesFromServer(Scanner scanner)` method

Client output is only

```
Welcome!
1 - Log In
2 - Sign up
3 - Exit
```

And I cannot provide string to be printed on the server.. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read by line, BufferedReader is a good choice

Try this, worked fine on my IDEA

```
package com.zhouplus;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    private static void startHandler(final Socket socket) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                BufferedReader inputFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter outPutToUser = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                outPutToUser.println("Welcome!");
                sendInitialCommandsToUser(outPutToUser);
                System.out.println("start readline!");
                System.out.println(inputFromUser.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    private static void sendInitialCommandsToUser(PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.println("1 - Log In");
        writer.println("2 - Sign up");
        writer.println("3 - Exit");
        writer.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);
        Socket accept = ss.accept();
        startHandler(accept);
    }
}
```

and the client

```
package com.zhouplus;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner inputFromUser = new Scanner(System.in);

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5555);
        BufferedReader inputFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter outputToServer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());


        String greetingFromServer = inputFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println(greetingFromServer);

        new Thread(() -> {
            String str = inputFromUser.nextLine();
            outputToServer.println(str);
            outputToServer.flush();
        }).start();

        getMultipleLinesFromServer(inputFromServer);
    }

    private static void getMultipleLinesFromServer(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String str;
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.out.println("over");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use both, nothing seems to work properly

Comment: look at my update, just put your input into a new thread, so that it will not be blocked by readline()  :p

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Javadocs of the Scanner hasNextLine method...

> ```
>  Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.
>  This method may block while waiting for input. The scanner does not
>  advance past any input.
> ```

It appears that once it has printed "3 - Exit" it is blocking to wait for more data from the server.

Comment: Hmmm, I've actually tried a method like this


`private static void getMultipleLinesFromServer(Scanner scanner)
    {
        String lineToBePrinted;
        while((lineToBePrinted = scanner.nextLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(lineToBePrinted);
        }
    }`


And I've also tried to do it even without any method, write 2-3 lines and it gets stucked anyway